# How to handle errors efficiently to prevent misleading results?

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, web-scraping

I've written some code in vba to find certain identities against some names in some websites. The code is working well if everything in it's right order, i meant if the link is valid, the name matches with `a` tags and finally the regex can find the identity. If any of the three or all of the three are bad searches then the script throws error. I've already specified the position where error occurs in my below script.

All i expect from you experts to provide me with any solution as to how i can handle the errors and let my script continue until all the links are exhausted.

As I do not have much knowledge on VBA so i tried with `On error resume next` to skip the errors. However, it turns out to be a clear mess when i take a look at the results. I'm pasting a rough example what i get when i use `On error resume next`.

```
Sub Identity_Finder()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, link As Variant, refined_links As String
    Dim rxp As New RegExp, identity As Object

    For Each link In [{"http://spltech.in/","http://www.unifrostindia.com/","http://www.unitfrostindia.com/","http://www.greenplanet.in/"}]
        With http
            .Open "GET", link, False
            .send                    '''throws here the first error if the link is invalid
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        For Each post In html.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If InStr(post.innerText, "certain_name") > 0 Then refined_links = post.href: Exit For
        Next post

        With http
            .Open "GET", refined_links, False
            .send                          ''throws another error here if no such link is found
        End With

        With rxp
            .Pattern = "some_regex"
            .Global = True
            Set identity = .Execute(http.responseText) 
        End With

        r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = link
        Cells(r, 2) = identity(0)    ''''throws another error here if no such identity is noticed

    Next link
End Sub
```

Upon using `On error resume next` What i get:

```
John executive
Mac lawyer
lulu lawyer
Robin lawyer 
Cathy student
```

Expected output:

```
John executive
Mac lawyer
lulu 
Robin  
Cathy student
```

The empty fields (when they are not found) are getting filled in with the previous values when i use `On error resume next`. How can I get around this misleading result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tied running the code step-by-step to see where the logic is going? If you start your code by press `F8` and then press again to go to the next line of the code and so on... It's great for debugging logic problems :)

Comment: Yes I debugged several times and I could find no issues if the link is not invalid, name matches with `a` tag and regex found the identity what I've already described in my post. However, I get error when either of the three doesn't matches the searches and I've already marked the position in my script where error occurs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to `error trap` in VBA is to

**1)** actually test the inputs / results before running them either through custom-made functions or built-in coding concepts or a mix of both.

**2)** Use VBA built-in error-handling if absolutely needed

**Example 1**

For example. You can wrap this statement with a custom function to test if a URL is valid or not.

```
With http
    .Open "GET", link, False
    .send                    '''throws here the first error if the link is invalid
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

If ValidURL Then 

    With http
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send     
         html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

End If
```

Where ValidURL is a function defined as:

```
Function ValidURL(URL as String) as Boolean

     Dim result as Boolean
    'I don't know how you would specify a valid link in your specific case
    'but that code goes here
    'a dummy example follows
     result = Left(URL,7) = "http://"
     ValidURL = result 'True or False

End Function
```

**Example 2**

I assume in this statement:

```
    With http
        .Open "GET", refined_links, False
        .send                          ''throws another error here if no such link is found
    End With
```

there is a specific error number (code) that is produced when no such link is found. Discover that number and use this code to bypass.

```
With http
    .Open "GET", refined_links, False
    On Error Resume Next
    .Send
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

If err.Number <> 9999 'replace with correct number

    'continue with regex test

End If
```

---

**PUTTING IT ALL TOGETHER**

Finally putting that all together you can build like so, with minimal use of `On Error Resume Next` and no `GoTo` statements.

```
For Each link In [{"http://spltech.in/","http://www.unifrostindia.com/","http://www.unitfrostindia.com/","http://www.greenplanet.in/"}]

    If ValidURL(link) Then 

        With http
            .Open "GET", link, False
            .send     
             html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        For Each post In html.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If InStr(post.innerText, "certain_name") > 0 Then refined_links = post.href: Exit For
        Next post

        With http
            .Open "GET", refined_links, False
            On Error Resume Next
            .Send
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        If err.Number <> 9999 'replace with correct number

            With rxp
                .Pattern = "some_regex"
                .Global = True
                Set identity = .Execute(http.responseText) 
            End With

            'i will leave it to you on how to account for no pattern match
            r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = link
            Cells(r, 2) = identity(0)    ''''throws another error here if no such identity is noticed

        End If

    End If

Next link
```

Comment: if you have no way to determine if a link is valid or not until you call `.Send` you can error trap the same way as in example 2.

Comment: Your code looks awesomely nice in it's appearance. I'll get back to you when I'm done checking. Thanks a lot for your time and effort @Scott Holtzman.